# How to delete a remote branch without deleting the local on git?

Tags: git

Does `git push origin :<branch>` delete the local branch as well? I need to save my local changes but delete the remote branch, and I can't test out creating a new branch/pushing and deleting right now. If not, is there any other way to delete a remote branch but keep the local branch/changes in the branch?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it doesn't delete the local branch. Doing the command you stated does exactly what you want.